# C#. Min path from left top corner to right bottom on ( n x n ) table

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, indexoutofrangeexception

Im having trouble with code, I get

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

in the first loop in the `find()` method. 
Could you guys help me? I cant figure out whats wrong.

I've found this code for java and changed a little bit for C#. In java code there was `int[][] A`, Ive changed it to `int[,]`. P.S on java, code works.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] A = { { 1, 7, 9, 2 }, { 8, 6, 3, 2 }, { 1, 6, 7, 8 },
            { 2, 9, 8, 2 } };
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", find(A));
    }

    public static int find(int[,] A)
    {
        int[,] solution = new int[A.Length + 1, A.Length + 1];

        solution[0, 0] = A[0, 0];

        for(int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            solution[0, i] = A[0, i] + solution[0, i - 1]; //IndexOutOfRangeException
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            solution[i, 0] = A[i, 0] + solution[i - 1, 0];
        }

        for(int i = 1; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < A.Length; j++)
            {
                solution[i, j] = A[i, j] 
                    + Math.Min(solution[i - 1, j], solution[i, j - 1]);
            }
        }
        return solution[A.Length - 1, A.Length - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to tell which line is the 26th.

Comment: I told. First loop in find() method. 
"solution[0, i] = A[0, i] + solution[0, i - 1];"

Comment: do you expect the answer to be 29 ?

Comment: Yes. I get 29 now. But maybe someone know how to change it that it would find MAX path?

Comment: what would you expect the answer to be? 40 ?

Comment: Just a side comment - It is good convention to name your methods with a capital letter and parameters with small. Also a more descriptive names of parameters might be good idea. (Here it is not of an issue, but later, when you have 6 parameters A, B, C, D E and F ... ;-)). So in the end I would propose something like `Find(int[,] table)`.

Comment: Yes, but with this ({ 1, 8, 4, 7 }, { 5, 2, 3, 1 }, { 6, 4, 7, 9 }, { 1, 3, 9, 3 }) I get 35 instead of 33. Seems to be working bad when changing Math.Min to Math.Max in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in a jagged array ([,]) the property `Length` will give you the overall amount of elements, in your case `A.Length == 16` but you want only one dimension. The solution would be to use `GetLength`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < A.GetLength(1); i++)
```

you need to use `0` for the X-Dimension and `1` for the Y-Dimenstion ( [X,Y])
 see the [documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.

This is how your method should look like:

```
public static int find(int[,] A)
{
    int[,] solution = new int[A.GetLength(0) + 1, A.GetLength(1)+ 1];

    solution[0, 0] = A[0, 0];

    for (int i = 1; i < A.GetLength(1); i++)
    {
        solution[0, i] = A[0, i] + solution[0, i - 1];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        solution[i, 0] = A[i, 0] + solution[i - 1, 0];
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < A.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < A.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            solution[i, j] = A[i, j]
                + Math.Min(solution[i - 1, j], solution[i, j - 1]);
        }
    }
    return solution[A.GetLength(0) - 1, A.GetLength(1) - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! You have saved me. :)

Comment: you are welcome. Debugging helps to find out, why you run into out of bounds :)